# Programmatically creating different log files using log4j

Tags: java, log4j

I have an automated integration test harness and would like to streamline the logging (which is implemented using log4j)

I have a number of high-level tests, each with an id and require a **separate** log file per test.  As the tests are created randomly the ids are not known until runtime.

Therefore I would like to ensure that logging within each high-level test is written out to the log file for that test.

I don't want to create custom log levels, neither do I want to have logging sent to all appenders.

Does anyone know a way of doing this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can easily invoke log4j's API programmatically, e.g.

```
FileAppender appender = new FileAppender();
// configure the appender here, with file location, etc
appender.activateOptions();

Logger logger = getRootLogger();
logger.addAppender(appender);
```

The `logger` can be the root logger as in this example, or any logger down the tree. Your unit test can add its custom appender during steup, and remove the appender (using `removeAppender()`) during teardown.