# logging the output of a map reduce job to a text file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I've been using this jobclient.monitorandprintjob() method to print the output of a map reduce job to the console. My usage is something like this:

```
job_client.monitorAndPrintJob(job_conf, job_client.getJob(j.getAssignedJobID()))
```

The output of which is as follows (printed on the console):

```
13/03/04 07:20:00 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201302211725_10139<br>
13/03/04 07:20:01 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%<br>
13/03/04 07:20:08 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%<br>
13/03/04 07:20:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%<br>
13/03/04 07:20:13 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201302211725_10139<br>
13/03/04 07:20:13 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 26<br>
13/03/04 07:20:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters<br>
13/03/04 07:20:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched reduce tasks=1<br>
13/03/04 07:20:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Aggregate execution time of mappers(ms)=5539<br>
13/03/04 07:20:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0<br>
13/03/04 07:20:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0<br>
13/03/04 07:20:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=2<br>
13/03/04 07:20:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=2<br>
13/03/04 07:20:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Aggregate execution time of reducers(ms)=4337<br>
13/03/04 07:20:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters<br>
13/03/04 07:20:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     MAPRFS_BYTES_READ=583<br>
13/03/04 07:20:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     MAPRFS_BYTES_WRITTEN=394<br>
13/03/04 07:20:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=140219<br>
13/03/04 07:20:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework<br>
13/03/04 07:20:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=6<br>
13/03/04 07:20:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce shuffle bytes=136<br>
13/03/04 07:20:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=22<br>
13/03/04 07:20:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=116<br>
13/03/04 07:20:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     CPU_MILLISECONDS=1320<br>
13/03/04 07:20:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input bytes=64<br>
13/03/04 07:20:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=13<br>
13/03/04 07:20:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=180<br>
13/03/04 07:20:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=11<br>
13/03/04 07:20:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=11<br>
13/03/04 07:20:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=11<br>
13/03/04 07:20:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     PHYSICAL_MEMORY_BYTES=734961664<br>
13/03/04 07:20:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=11<br>
13/03/04 07:20:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     VIRTUAL_MEMORY_BYTES=9751805952<br>
13/03/04 07:20:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=13<br>
13/03/04 07:20:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     GC time elapsed (ms)=0<br>
```

I would like the above output/log to be printed in a text file, rather than the console. any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your HADOOP_HOME/conf you may find one file named : `log4j.properties`. I believe you can configure where and how to log in there.

To be precise, you shall be using a *rolling file appender*, so you shall un-comment(just remove `#`) the following lines from `log4j.properties` file:

```
# Rolling File Appender
#

#log4j.appender.RFA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
#log4j.appender.RFA.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.log.file}

# Logfile size and and 30-day backups
#log4j.appender.RFA.MaxFileSize=1MB
#log4j.appender.RFA.MaxBackupIndex=30

#log4j.appender.RFA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.RFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c{2} - %m%n
#log4j.appender.RFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c{2} (%F:%M(%L)) - %m%n
```

And customize the other parameters to your liking.

For more about log4j configurations, read [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration).

Comment: thanks for your response @amar. However, i do not have access to the hadoop conf files at the moment. can i use log4j apis or can i programatically transfer the logs into a text file rather than modifying the properties file?

Comment: where are you executing hadoop from?

Comment: you may even have your own properties file and point to that from command line while running hadoop : `-Dlog4j.configuration=my-log4j.properties`

Comment: i would try the solution suggested by you. but is it also possible programatically?

Comment: yes I think so, it should be possible programmatically too. look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191070/controlling-logging-functionality-in-hadoop

Comment: thanks again @amar, but i'm using apache commons logging. how do i change the configurations in this case programatically?