# Dynamic logfile naming based on input?

Tags: java, log4j

My application takes an argument as input and all the other processes happen based on this argument

I would like to create log file with name based on the input parameter

Can anyone let me know how I can do this ?

I am using Log4J 1.2.17.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965946/configuring-log4j-loggers-programmatically) should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from the log4j manual [Read Configuration section](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

 // BasicConfigurator replaced with PropertyConfigurator.
 PropertyConfigurator.configure(args[0]); //args[0] path to your log4 conf file   
}
```

Comment: I am trying this, but I want to validate the input of course & also want to log the messages before.. Any other ideas?

Comment: You need to configure the logger before logging. For other ideas to come you need to explain more in your original question. Why do you need it ? How are you going to use logging result? Do you really need such solution or it can be solved differently?

Comment: I guess I can use your approach + writing to console for my use case. Thanks a lot