# How to configure log4j to log only info messages and higher?

Tags: java, log4j

I don't use config or xml files for configuring log4j as there no need to configure it deeply. I only need to print messages to the console. so I do this:

```
BasicConfigurator.configure();
```

and to print only info and higher messages I do this:

```
Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class)
LOG.setLevel(Level.INFO);
```

But nevertheless I see debug messages in the console too. But I only need info and actually error messages to be printed.

How to do this?

**UPD:** I created a config file with the which contains, as described in the tutorial here: 
[manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) the following:

```
  log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

  # Direct log messages to stdout
  log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
  log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
  log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
  log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L        %m%n

log4j.logger.com.messagedna.facade=INFO
log4j.logger.com.messagedna.receiver=INFO
log4j.logger.com.messagedna.util=INFO
log4j.logger.com.messagedna.parser=INFO
```

I put it to the `com.messagedna`

In every class I need logger in I wrote the following:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
try {
    props.load(new FileInputStream("/log4j.properties"));
    } catch (Exception e){
      LOG.error(e);
      }
PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
```

but when I run my app I get the following:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.messagedna.server.util.Config).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Comment: Your log4j lives at the root of your file system?!

Comment: I can't operate whith such concepts. Do you mean where the config file is or what else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only setting the level for messages logged using the logger for `MyClass.class`, however any messages at debug level on other loggers will still get printed.

What you really need to do is to set the log level on the console log handler (which is responsible for printing all log messages to the console). However doing this whilst using `BasicConfigurator` will be quite tricky to do, you are better off moving to having your logging configuration specified in a properties file (which is much more flexible).

I would advise working through the [log4j logging configuration tutorial](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) - this will help you put together exactly the configuration you want, and should prove a worthwhile investment of your time. However, if you want to get this done quickly, try adding the content below to the file `log4j.properties` ([example taken from here](http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/)):

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

And then changing your code to do the following:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream("/my/path/to/log4j.properties"));
PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
```

Comment: where shall I get Properties?

Comment: This is found at `java.util.Properties` - sorry should have made that clear

Comment: If I use your variant i get the following: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.messagedna.server.util.Config).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Comment: According to the link in the error, 'No appenders could be found for logger' happens when the configuration file cannot be found - did you set the path to the file correctly? The configuration is setting up the root logger, therefore there should be an appender for the logger `com.messagedna.server.util.Config` if the configuration is read.

Comment: ok, I configured settings for every class and still have the same output

Comment: This shouldn't make a difference - the root logger is configured in the settings and should cover all the other loggers. All I suspect is that the logger configuration is not being read - could you print out the contents of `props` after calling `props.load` and verify that the properties in the file are all loaded into the Properties object?

Comment: I tryed to print the random property like System.out.println(props.getProperty("log4j.appender.stdout")) and it prints null

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32826/discussion-between-robjohncox-and-nikitin-mikhail)

Answer (score 3):

Configure log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1

log4j.logger.com.MYPACKAGE=INFO, A1

log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
```

Comment: I see. and to which place shall I put this file? to the package I use logger in?

Comment: Ok look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965946/configuring-log4j-loggers-programmatically but I don't recommend it, why complicate everithing when not need it

Comment: @NikitinMikhail it may seem simpler to have this in the code, but you will find it much more powerful and flexible to move the config to a file (this will become more and more useful as your application grows) and it's really not much effort to move to using a configuration file.

Comment: As you need for your project!! @robjohncox is giving you the alternative

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to use to do it only by code

Heres a alternative.

Do this at the start, a static code initialization will work

```
logger = Logger.getLogger(Class.getName(), factory);
logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
```

Having said that, theres no excuse for not using log4j.xml. Its very easy to use one.

Comment: which factory did you mean?

Comment: any class that implements LoggerFactory