# Where to put log4j.xml on tomcat 7?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, struts2

I'm currently developing a Java Struts2 webapp (using Maven) and have successfully configured the use of datasources to connect with the database. Since May application needs the ability of being moved between environments (Development > Homologation > Production), it must use  server config files to load paramenters (such as the datasources and log levels).

I can't find any references on how to configure a java webapp to use a log4j.xml file from outside the application (out of the WAR). With maven I simply put the log4j.xml inside my `src/main/resources` folder and it loads automatically. What should I do to ensure that my webapp loads a external log4j.xml file on deploy?

Comment: Configure Log4J programmatically, maybe in a custom ServletContextListener or @WebListener, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965946/configuring-log4j-loggers-programmatically)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maven by default places all files from `src/main/resources` into `/WEB-INF/classes/`. With log4j, you can specify where your configuration file is located with help of Web App Deployment Descriptor (`web.xml`). Simply, add log4j listener:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And context parameter:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

`classpath:` is equivalent to `/WEB-INF/classes`,  you may specify any path for example, with `${catalina.home}`, a tomcat specific variable. Use it with `file://` prefix

Comment: @Stefoan Everything today needs it.

Comment: @Stefoan Struts2 has integrated with Spring well, so it's not a problem to use this listener.

Comment: When using maven it is also necessary to add `spring-core` and `spring-web` dependencies.

Comment: What about log4j2?