# Configuring Log4j2 log location runtime

Tags: log4j2

I have a requirement where i need to change the log location dynamically depending on the parameter received from command line. Like i will be receiving $LogLocation parameter from another input and now i have to generate my logs in location "$LogLocation/test/log"
I am using log4j2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [override log4j configuration programmatically: file location for FileAppender](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242521/override-log4j-configuration-programmatically-file-location-for-fileappender)

Comment: @Hitham S. AlQadheeb, The one you pointed above is for log4j. I am facing issue with log4j2.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668938/how-to-configure-logger-programmatically-in-log4j2-02

Comment: I solved the issue, but stack overflow has banned me from answering.

Comment: If you can't post an answer yet,  then just describe the solution in a comment.  It might help someone.

Comment: Solution : I used the ThreadContext like as shown below. ThreadContext.put("LogLocation ", commandLineArgs.get("LogLocation "));  Then loading the log configuration from log4j2.xml. Above parameter is extracted in log4j2.xml as shown below <Properties>
  <Property name="filename">$${ctx:LogLocation}/test/log</Property>
 </Properties>  and then use this 'filename' like <RollingFile name="ROLLING" fileName="${filename}