# Cassandra debug logging in JBoss 4.2.3

Tags: jboss, cassandra, log4j, cassandra-2.0

I am using Cassandra with JBoss 4.2.3.
I am trying to configure the debug logs of Cassandra in jboss-log4j.xml by following [this link](http://datastax.github.io/java-driver/2.0.10/features/logging/):

```
<logger name="com.datastax.driver.core" additivity="false">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</logger>

<logger name="com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster" additivity="false">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</logger>

<logger name="com.datastax.driver.core.Session" additivity="false">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</logger>

<logger name="com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler" additivity="false">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</logger>

<logger name="com.datastax.driver.core.Connection" additivity="false">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</logger>

<root>
  <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
  <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

But JBoss is not picking it up. It works fine from standlone java program.
How do I make it work ?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question though this may not be a perfect solution:
Since I couldn't do it through the configuration files, I did it programmatically as below using [Link1](http://robertmaldon.blogspot.in/2007/09/programmatically-configuring-log4j-and.html) and [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965946/configuring-log4j-loggers-programmatically):

```
        FileAppender fa = new FileAppender();
        fa.setName("FileLogger");
        fa.setFile("${jboss.server.home.dir}/all/log/Cassandra.log");
        fa.setLayout(new PatternLayout(PatternLayout.TTCC_CONVERSION_PATTERN));
        fa.setThreshold(Level.TRACE);
        fa.setAppend(true);
        fa.activateOptions();

        Logger rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger();
        Logger cassandraLogger = rootLogger.getLoggerRepository().getLogger("com.datastax.driver.core");
        cassandraLogger.setLevel(Level.TRACE);
        cassandraLogger.addAppender(fa);
```