# How to set log4j 2.x output path after reading in log4j.xml

Tags: java, xml, log4j, log4j2

Say I have an appender defined in the log4j.xml file below.

```
<appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
            <param name="File" value="/home/logs/oarm_log.txt" />
            <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH" />
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                 <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p[app=%log4j.webapp.name%] [%t] %c - %m\n" />
            </layout>
    </appender>
```

How could I change the value **"/home/logs/oarm_log.txt"** to a different value that comes from a string found in the actual Java code so that the code determines where to output the .txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though your best go-to resource for this would be Log4j's [official documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html), I will list out two more references that can help you out.

Baeldung is one of my favourite Java blogs. You can go through [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/log4j2-programmatic-config).

You can also refer to this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9003191/1556966).

If you are in a hurry, have a look at the below code snippet.

```
        final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
        final Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
        final Layout layout = PatternLayout.createDefaultLayout(config);
        Appender appender = FileAppender.createAppender("path/to/logFile.log", "false", "false", "File", "true",
            "false", "false", "4000", layout, null, "false", null, config);
        appender.start();
        config.addAppender(appender);
        AppenderRef ref = AppenderRef.createAppenderRef("File", null, null);
        AppenderRef[] refs = new AppenderRef[] {ref};
        LoggerConfig loggerConfig = LoggerConfig.createLogger("false", "info", "org.apache.logging.log4j",
            "true", refs, null, config, null );
        loggerConfig.addAppender(appender, null, null);
        config.addLogger("org.apache.logging.log4j", loggerConfig);
        ctx.updateLoggers();
```