# save log of junit test case to separate file by log4j

Tags: java, junit, log4j

I have massive junit test cases which are run by JunitCore.run()
Now I want to save log for each case to separate files, but my application is using log4j, all log ouput are saved in a single big file.
How can I create individual log for each case? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive this might resolve your issues...

[Creating Separate Files via Log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666121/programmatically-creating-different-log-files-using-log4j)

You can specify various files for different appenders.

Answer (score 0):

1.You have to remove all the existing appenders on the loger object (loggerOBject.removeALLApenders() ; )

2.Define a new pattern for the logger
use PatternLayout API
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html

3. Create a new file appender and pass the logpath  you want to CREATE/LOG into to the  FileAppender constructor

   FileAppender appender = new FileAppender(layout,logpath,false);
4. Add appender object to the Logger object

   log.add(appender);
5. Set the level of the logger

   logger.setLevel((Level) Level.INFO);