# Set log4j logfile at runtime

Tags: java, dynamic, log4j, filenames, slf4j

I am working on a java program that's using slf4j. Presently, the program contains the following lines:

```
 class MyOwn{
    Logger logger; //org.slf4j.*;
    static {
    PropertyConfigurator.configure("somePathTo/log4j.properties");//log4j
    logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyOwn.class);
}

     ... // rest of my code is here
 }
```

My question is this: What modifications do I need to do so that I can specify the name of the logFile at runtime.

Background: Basically, while the program is running, it is supposed to do `x` number of jobs sequentially. For each job, I want a different fileName.

The log4j.properties file is not xml; it's text and I must keep it that way. I found this link (http://cognitivecache.blogspot.com/2008/08/log4j-writing-to-dynamic-log-file-for.html) but I am not sure how to use the information there.

EDIT

Below is my current log4j.properties file. I want to be able to keep the file directory set in the log4j.properties file (i.e. `/opt/stuff/var/log/jmy/proj/`) and just replace `myown.log` with the dynamic file name. How would I do that? Again, I want to keep the log4j.properties.

```
 log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.     log4j.ConsoleAppender
 log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.     log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c{1} - %m%n

 log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CONSOLE

 log4j.appender.MY_OWN_ERR_LOG=org.apache.     log4j.RollingFileAppender
 log4j.appender.MY_OWN_ERR_LOG.File=/opt/stuff/var/log/jmy/proj/myown.error.log
 log4j.appender.MY_OWN_ERR_LOG.MaxFileSize=4MB
 log4j.appender.MY_OWN_ERR_LOG.MaxBackupIndex=3
 log4j.appender.MY_OWN_ERR_LOG.layout=org.apache.     log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.MY_OWN_ERR_LOG.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c{1} - %m%n
 log4j.appender.MY_OWN_ERR_LOG.Threshold = WARN

 log4j.appender.MY_OWN_LOG=org.apache.     log4j.RollingFileAppender
 log4j.appender.MY_OWN_LOG.File=/opt/stuff/var/log/jmy/proj/myown.log
 log4j.appender.MY_OWN_LOG.MaxFileSize=8MB
 log4j.appender.MY_OWN_LOG.MaxBackupIndex=3
 log4j.appender.MY_OWN_LOG.layout=org.apache.     log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.MY_OWN_LOG.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c{1} - %m%n

 log4j.logger.my.own.things=DEBUG, MY_OWN_LOG, MY_OWN_ERR_LOG
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this post [Programmatically creating different log files using log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666121/programmatically-creating-different-log-files-using-log4j)

You can specify anything you can put in a log4j.properties file programatically. You just create the appender and logger objects and link them together.

Also see here for a fuller example: http://configlog4jbyprogram.blogspot.co.uk/

Comment: I have been playing around with your suggestion. I got stuck so I have edited the post. I tried `FileAppender appender = (FileAppender) logger.getAppender("MY_OWN_LOG"); File file = new File(appender.getFile());`. I get a NullPointerException. I use `MY_OWN_LOG` because of `log4j.appender.MY_OWN_LOG=org.apache.     log4j.RollingFileAppender`

Comment: Where are you getting the NPE? If it's appender that is null, I'd suggest your log4j properties file isn't being picked up (so there is no logger named MY_OWN_LOG). How are you getting the logger object? Also, if you are still using log4j.properties, why not just define different appenders in there for each file you want?